# Python subprocess on Windows

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a Windows executable that I am trying to run from within a python script on a Windows 2016 server.  Basically, I do this:

```
import subprocess

myCmd = 'run.exe foo'
result = subprocess.run(myCmd) # tried it with & without shell=True
```

If I run this from a python or ipython shell, it works just fine.  If I run it from my script, it does nothing, but it gives a return code of 0 (result -> CompletedProcess(args='run.exe foo', returncode=0).

Obviously I am doing something wrong :(.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you are in the right directory so it can find `run.exe`? you can try putting the full path to `run.exe`

EDIT: according to https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run you need to run `subprocess.run(myCmd.split(' '))`, or `subprocess.run([myCmd], shell=True)` but the later might open you to shell injection vulnerabilities if you craft myCmd based on user input

Comment: Hi new stacker, welcome. please use comments unless you have an answer =/

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment everywhere yet.

Comment: `subprocess.run(myCmd.split(' ')), or subprocess.run([myCmd], shell=True, capture_output=True)` this looks good. Not sure, but the addition of capture_output may be needed to capture stdout.

Comment: And maybe suggest putting the full path to the executable in the command string.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I have tried full paths and ./run.exe (as this is all in the same directory) without any luck.  It gets weirder.  I can run the mini script I show above, and it works just fine (python mini_process.py).  However, if I change my subprocess.run in my "real" script to run the mini script rather than the executable, it also completes with a return code of 0, but the file that should be created (which is created when the mini script is run separately) is not created.  What could I be doing in the one script that could cause this behavior?

Comment: it might be a problem in the executable. what does it do?

Comment: To clarify further, I have tried subprocess.run(mycmd.split(' '), shell=True, capture_output=True).  It makes no difference except the return is now: "CompletedProcess(args=['run.exe', 'foo'], returncode=0, stdout=b'', stderr=b'')".  It stil doesn't create the output file, but running the mini script above, works just fine (unless I run it from inside my "real" script).  The executable just compares two files and produces a third file based on that.  It works fine from the command line or if run by that mini script.

Comment: can you try making an hello world executable and see if it produces an output?

Comment: In the words of Emily Litella (or Gilda Radner), "Never mind".  It seems I had a typo.  All is good now.

Thanks!

Comment: bwahahahahahaha @AlG